# 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel 9 Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I run following migration code. its return following Error

**Error :**

```
1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `company_address_user` add c  
  onstraint `company_address_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

**Code**

```
Schema::create('company_address_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_address_id');
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'company_address_id']);
        });

        Schema::table('company_address_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign(['user_id'])->references(['id'])->on('users');
            $table->foreign(['company_address_id'])->references(['id'])->on('company_addresses');
        });
```

Comment: Why 2 primary keys for `company_address_user` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('company_address_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('company_address_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('company_addresses')
        ->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->unique(['user_id', 'company_address_id']);
});
```